# Recognizing subview's class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I decided to animate my objects manually and therefore made an extension for `UIView` class:

```
public extension UIView{

    func slideOut(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { self.frame.origin.x = -self.frame.width }, completion: finishedDisposing)
    }

    func finishedDisposing(successfully: Bool){
        if !successfully{
            ((UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController as! VC).showSystemMessage("Failed to dispose one or more subviews from superview", ofType: .NOTICE)
        }

        responder.viewDisposed()
    }

}
```

Which works nice and I have no problems about it, BUT I have a method in VC (Custom `UIViewController`) `viewDisposed()` which is called whenever a view slides out of sight and it has such an implementation:

```
func viewDisposed() {
        disposed++
        print("Updated disposed: \(disposed) / \(self.view.subviews.count)")

        if disposed == self.view.subviews.count - 1{
            delegate.vcFinishedDisposing()
        }
    }
```

It shows that `self.view.subviews` contains all my custom views + 3 more (UIView, _UILayoutGuide x 2). They do extend UIView although do not call`responder.viewDisposed` method. My decision was to figure out how to get classes of each subview and `Mirror(reflecting: subView).subjectType` if I print it does it wonderfully. Is there any way to actually compare this to anything or, better, get `String` representation? Basically, I want you to help me create a method which would create a stack of subviews which are not of type UIView (only subClasses) nor _UILayoutGuide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better off directly creating an array of just the subviews you care about, instead of starting with **all** subviews and trying to filter out the ones you don't care about. Those layout guides weren't always there—they were added in iOS 7. Who knows what else Apple will add in the future?

Anyway:

```
let mySubviews = view.subviews.filter {
    !["UIView", "_UILayoutGuide"].contains(NSStringFromClass($0.dynamicType))
}
```